# Apple developer iOS device registered limit reached

Tags: ios, device

100 of 100 available devices have been registered on our corporate developer program.  What are some suggested ways to continue device debugging using same program without having to signup for another developer program?

Answer (score 2):

TestFlight external testing is really your only option if the devices already in the list are insufficient. You can get up to 1k externals that way.

Be sure to clear out unneeded devices as well; that won't help you today (removing devices doesn't lower the number immediately) but when the opportunity to "reset" comes along, you'll be ready.